# Error: Build of instance c1192e0a-e815-4f4e-b995-05d0c6bd2dfc aborted: Failed to allocate the network(s), not rescheduling?

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron

`enter code here's get this error when building a machine in OpenStack
I checked Nova service logs and received this error

Error: Build of instance c1192e0a-e815-4f4e-b995-05d0c6bd2dfc aborted: Failed to allocate the network(s), not rescheduling

Comment: This seems more appropriate for Serverfault rather than here, as it doesn't seem to be related to programming.

Comment: Look for other errors related to this instance in the Nova logs. Also try to find errors in the Neutron logs.

Comment: Provide further info: What are the parameters of this launch? Do all instance launches fail like that? What kind of cloud is that and how was it created? Which Nova version is this?

Comment: OpenStack ussuri @berndbausch

Comment: check Neutron logs not error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stop rabitmq1 and rabitmq2 and rabitmq3 after that I start rabitmq3 and rabitmq2 and rabitmq1 after that reboot Lxc neutron finally I could fix error

Answer (score 0):

It is often a case when Neutron is unable to create and/or attach a new network port, to further investige on the causes you need to have a look to neutron logs.

Access to your controller host(s) and read the log flow using something like:

```
tail -f /var/log/kolla/neutron/*.log
```

if you are using kolla-ansible to deploy your cluster, or

```
tail -f /var/log/containers/neutron/*.log
```

if you are operating on a containerized distribution, or

```
tail -f /var/log/neutron/*.log
```

if it's a process based system

If you can post some log fragment we can help you to get closer to address the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered this error but have not any tips in those logs.

Get some error info from `openstack server show error_instance`:

```
..._build_and_run_instance nova.exception.BuildAbortException: Build of instance aborted: Failed to allocate the networks(s), not rescheduling...
```

And I check my hypervisor's ip info:

```
9: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master brmgt state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether bc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
10: bond1.320@bond1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master brcls state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether be brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
15: brq12805e86-a2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
17: rename17@bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether bc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
19: tap79852d9e-f7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master brq12805e86-a2 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Obviously, the interface name `rename17@bond0` has wrong format instead of the name is `bond0.999@bond0` in previous hypervisor.

I fixed it by:

```
mv /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules.bak
ip l d rename17
docker restart neutron_linuxbridge_agent
```

PS: in my case, we are use `linuxbridge` and `vlan`'s network.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps:

- Modify the **/etc/nova/nova.conf** file on the compute node

  add the following configuration:

  > vif_plugging_timeout = 10
  >
  > vif_plugging_is_fatal = False
- Restart the Nova service on the compute node.

  > $ openstack service nova-compute restart
- Create the VM again.